# PHP login validation when user is not active

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I developed a PHP login system that when the user logs in and the account is still not activated by the admin it will display `message2` and if the user inputs wrong credentials it will display `mesage1`

I am almost done with the work. but i am confused on why the condition always falls under `message1`.

here is my code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
      // windows
      // $servername = "localhost";
      // $username = "root";
      // $password = "";
      // $dbname = "loginDB";

      // linux
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "gmg0ddepfrxs";
      $dbname = "loginDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn){
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $uname = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["pwd"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='$uname' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $utype = $row["user_type"]; //1
      $status = $row["user_status"]; //0
      $username = $row["user_name"]; //USERNAME
      $password = $row["password"]; //PASSWORD NG USER
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 AND $utype == '1'){
      // session_start();
      $_SESSION["login"] = "access";
      setcookie("name",$uname,false);     
      echo "<script>window.location.href=\"member.php\"</script>"; 
    }elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0) {
      echo "<script>window.location.href=\"index.php?msg=1\"</script>"; 
    }elseif ($utype == '0') {
      echo "<script>window.location.href=\"index.php?msg=2\"</script>"; 
    }

 }
?>
```

here is my HTML code.

```html
<html>
<form action='login.php' method="post">
  <table cellspacing='5' align='center'>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td>
        <input required type='text' name='name' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td>
        <input required type='password' name='pwd' />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <?php if(isset($_GET[ "msg"])){
      $errmsg=$ _GET[ "msg"]; 
       if($errmsg==1 ){ echo "<div style='text-align: center;'><h5> <font color = \"red\ "> Incorrect username and/or password! have you registered? </font></div>"; } 
       elseif ($errmsg==2 ) { echo
  "<div style='text-align: center;'><h5> <font color = \"red\ "> Contact admin to activate your account. </font></div>"; } } ?>

</form>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="register.php">
    <button>Register here</button>
  </a>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: You need to add error checking to your query, you're assuming it always works.

Comment: that `if()` belongs inside `while()`. more importantly, the `$utype == '1'` however you may need to remove the quotes around the 1. That may be interpreted as a string, rather than an integer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi, thanks for answering. but its still not working.

Comment: you're welcome. another thing I forgot is that `if (mysqli_num_rows($result))` belongs before the `while`. you need to check if the row exists first, then `while`, then `if`. and check for errors too.

Comment: you also didn't post your HTML form, so it's unknown if it's correct, post method and name attributes for the POST arrays, and if your columns are long enough to accomodate the data etc. check for all that.

Comment: ok, it seems like I'm out of this loop. somebody posted an answer now. ask them.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- i've included the HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

use a simple header location to redirect your users:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "gmg0ddepfrxs";
  $dbname = "loginDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn){
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$uname = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["pwd"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='$uname' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $totalRows_result = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($totalRows_result == 0) {
           header("location: index.php?msg=1");}


  $utype = $row["user_type"]; //1
  $status = $row["user_status"]; //0

if ($utype == '1'){
        $_SESSION["login"] = "access";
  setcookie("name",$uname,false);     
 header("location: member.php"); 
} else {
   header("location: index.php?msg=2"); 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: a few extra edits to your code, let me know if it works to comment it better

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. but its still not working.

Comment: well i removed just now the while loop, as you will only get one result. can you try again?

Comment: sadly, it just outputs a blank page.

Comment: can you post your form and the structure of your users table?